# C# - How to deselect table cell in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop

I'm currently trying to produce the opposite effect of the Selection.SelectCell method.

Here is my code:

```
public void getCellContent()
{
    Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

    currentSelection.SelectCell();
    newKey = currentSelection.Text; //global variable
    currentSelection.Collapse();
}
```

Collapse Method set the cursor to the start of the cell.
Even if I set Collapse direction parameter to the end, the cursor going to the next cell.

My purpose is to be able to save content of a word table cell each time I type up in it (wihtout cell changing).

best regards,

Chefty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to set the cursor at the end of a text inside the cell of a Word table. Not without moving from a cell to another.

The only way to do that would have been using the following code:

```
currentSelection.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
currentSelection.MoveLeft(Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1);
```

Don't do it. Given the fact this would get called each time you type a character, it won't be fast and efficient enough and you will end up typing characters in the next cell.

You should save the content of your cell just once, when you change the selection on your own. When you type your first character, use the following code :

```
currentCell = currentSelection.Range.Cells[1]; //index always starts at 1, not 0
```

And when you click on another cell (you will maybe have to use Win32 API to catch such an event), don't forget to do :

```
currentCell.Select();
string currentCellContent = currentSelection.Text;
```

After that, you still end up with a selected cell, and still need to use `currentSelection.Collapse()`, but at least you got the content of your cell, and this by performing one save per edit.